# Validation is not functional

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having a problem in which my `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model."name")` for all my views they do not work they do not do anything when i leave them blank and produce no message, no error message nothing. I have created the application three times and re-placed all the code and still nothing does a person has to do something to make the validation messages to work if so how?

Thank You

This is ASP.NET C# MVC3

Comment: Is `model => model."name"` a typo?

Comment: No it is not a typo what it is in my view I have a many @htmlvalidationfor statements and to save time I just wrote the word "name" so it refers to all of them

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[Required]` to the property you're editing.

Comment: where do i put this? the controller or the view?

Comment: There is no such thing as a property model? yes a model but what is a property model? your answer was not clear. Can you please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Having `[Required]` along with your Model/ViewModel class property will do the trick.

```
public class LogOnModel
{
     [Required]  
     [Display(Name = "User name")]
     public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I shall try this and inform back

Comment: This has not worked I dont know what the problem is if i leave the filed empty it does nothing. Does anyone know why?